# ATI EAH4350 adapter configuration

Tags: ati

I have an ati eah4350 adapter and the latest Ubuntu 11.10.
I connected the adapter using HDMI and i didn't have sound.
So i installed fglrx using the readme from their site.

Now i have sound but the picture isn't smooth in videos as it was before installing
the fglrx.

How can it be repaired?
Thanks

Comment: What version of the fglrx drivers did you install?

Comment: latest from the ATI website

Comment: does it also happen if you are running Unity2D?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove and disable every `radeon` and `fglrx` packages from the official repository, just follow the instrunctions at this page http://wiki.cchtml.com/index.php/Main_Page and everything will run fine.

The HDMI audio bridge it's not automatically activated and you have to switch between your audio output devices using the "Audio Settings" menu under the volume control on the system bar. It's also probably useful for you to know that under the "gear icon" ( the one on the upper right corner ) there is a shortcut for the displays management.

Comment: thats what i've done but i still get a picture that is not smooth, from some reason the video before is better

Comment: read the part about the issues http://wiki.cchtml.com/index.php/Ubuntu_Oneiric_Installation_Guide#Issues take a special look at the tearing section.